# Как сделать так, что бы функция выводила переменные типа float c 2 цифрами после точки, а не с 6?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, структуры

У меня есть программа, которая будет выполнять задачи с обработкой массива структур. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать так, что бы при выводе массива элементы его структур с типом float сохраняли 2 цифры после точки (обозначают эти элементы время и не могут иметь больше 2 цифр после точки), а не 6, как сейчас выводит? Моя программа:

```
// Вывод массива на экран
void showAll(){
    cout << "\nAll routs today:\n" ;
    printf(" %-*s %10s %10s %10s\n", STAT_SIZE, "Routs",
                "Departure", "Number", "Price");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf(" %-*s %10f %9d %10d\n", STAT_SIZE, ar[i].stat,
               ar[i].time, ar[i].number, ar[i].price);
    }
    pause();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просьба, меньше кода, хватит лишь функции которая возвращает значение, хотя для данного вопроса можно и без кода вообще

Чтобы округлить до двух чисел можешь использовать это:

```
float value = 5.343456;
round(value*100)/100;
// out 5.34
```

Comment: Это не гарантирует вывода/наличия двух знаков после запятой

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Кода будет меньше

Answer (score 2):

Ну хранить меньше знаков float точно никак не может, но вывести с ограничением можно. Могу даже два способа дать:

1. Из языка C - `printf`. Для этого нужно подключить библиотеку stdio.h:

```
float a = 5.341352;
printf("%.2f", a);
```

2. Из C++ - `setprecision`. Для этого нужно подключить библиотеку iomanip:

```
float a = 5.341352;
cout << setprecision(3);
cout << a;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его как верный слева